# Trino Create table from Json

Tags: json, trino

I am trying to create a table on Trino
with Json as datasource using Hive Connector.

```
create table if not exists test.json_table
(
    "timestamp" STRING,
    "header" array[STRUCT<id:STRING, type:STRING, name:STRING, timestamp:STRING, name2:STRING, version:STRING>],
    "data" array[STRUCT<subtype:STRING, acc_number:STRING>]
)
WITH (
  external_location = 's3a://path/json-file',
  format = 'JSON'
);
```

This doesn't work in Trino. As the syntax seems to be different from Presto / Athena.

Can someone please advice! Thanks

Comment: what is the error that you are encountering ? Also post some sample JSON records if possible to your question

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure this out.

Do share if you have other ways to do SerDe

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.data(
    timestamp varchar, 
    header ROW(id varchar, type VARCHAR, client varchar)
    )
 WITH (
 format='json',
 external_location='s3a://path/json-file'
 );
```

Then query your data with header.id , header.type for example.